# Android - Testing That an Activity Throws an Exception

Tags: java, android

I have an activity which expects to have an extra set inside the calling intent as an input value. Since it's a very basic class and does not work without the extra, I want to test that an exception is throw each time the extra is not set (or if it's the wrong kind of object). I tried doing something like this:

```
     public class IntentAndroidGameTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<BaseActivity> {

        public BaseActivityTest() {
        super(BaseActivity.class);
        }

        @Test
        public void testCorrectSetUp() {
        setActivityIntent(createIntent(new CorrectExtra()));
        assertNotNull(getActivity());
        }

        @Test
        public void testSetUpWithoutExtra1() {
        setActivityIntent(createIntent(null));
        try {
            getActivity();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            assertEquals("Extra must be set!", e.getMessage());
        }
        }

        @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
        public void testSetUpWithoutExtra2() {
        setActivityIntent(createIntent(null));
        getActivity();
        }


        protected Intent createIntent(Serializable extra) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.putExtra("myExtra", extra);
        return intent;
        }
    }
```

The exeption is thrown, but the test takes it as a bad sign and points out:

> Test failed to run to completion. Reason: 'Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException''.

How can I intercept and tell the Android test that I WANT to have the exception?

Answer (score 0):

The test expects your code to actually throw the exception, and when you're catching it yourself you don't let the testing framework see it, in result the method exits without throwing the exception, and this is not the expected result. Remove the try-catch block and the test should pass.

Comment: No it does not. Neither the catch block nor the "expected" get to handle the exception, since the framework catches it before. But I edited the question so that one wouldn't believe I actually expect both to be triggered.

Comment: By the way, you want to test a case when the extra hasn't been set, but you're actually testing a case when the extra has been set to null. These are different things.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have to change that later, but for now I'd just be able to test that any kind of exception gets thrown.

Comment: This is probably not necessary, since what you'll be testing is system's behavior, and that's not something you should test.

Comment: You should test your application's behavior, since you're developing your application, not the system.

Comment: That's what I'm testing. o.O My application should throw a meaningful exception if the Intent was not set up correctly (because else I'll get an exception anyways, but something like a NPE miles away from where the intent is read).

Comment: If you're interested, let's discuss it in a separate chat.

Comment: I'm not interested in discussing anything. I want to test my API thoroughly, and if my API throws an exception, of course I have to test this, too.